# what does an equality inside a plot function in MATLAB mean?

Tags: matlab, signal, processing

So I´m just new on MATLAB and this may be a very silly doubt but when generating basic signals for signal processing I have this:

t = (-1:0.01:1)';

impulse = **t==0**;
plot(t,impulse)

(*from: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/gs/impulse-step-and-ramp-functions.html*)

So I know that will plot a unit impulse yet I can't see what t==0 is doing there. AT time instant = 0 it will go up to 1, as expected, but why?
More specifically, can anyone explain me what the "==" is telling MATLAB to do?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most programming languages you can take the expression that is fit for an "if" statement and use it in any calculation.

In most cases, when the expression is "TRUE", it will give the value "1" as result.

Therefore "t==0" evaluates to "1" when the value of "t" is zero (0)... in any other cases the result is zero.

This makes it possible to write code without "if"-statements that behaves the same as code using one or more if statements.

e.g.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> for x in xrange(0,20):
...  print (x!=10)*x,
... 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
>>> for x in xrange(0,20):
...  if x!=10:
...   print x,
...  else:
...   print 0,
... 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
>>> quit()
$
```

Comment: Great answer Hannu. Muchas gracias!